# Using jira rest api - how can I get description of a specific issue?

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use jira rest api that is available here https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/ and I'm trying to figure out how to get the description of the specific issue in my project.

When I do the following query:

> curl -D- -u user:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   "http://localhost/jira/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE_NUMBER_1"

I'm indeed getting the reponse of the whole body of that issue. It contains lots of fields, e.g. `"avatarUrls"`, `displayName`, but it also contains `body`. I'm interested in getting only the latter. How can I limit my query so that it only returns `body`? I've tried:

> curl -D- -u user:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   "http://localhost/jira/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE_NUMBER_1?fields=body"

but it doesn't work. What's the problem here?

Comment: I think the body s part of a other field in jira, like comment. You should be able to limit your result on the field in which the body you want is. Your method of using ?fields={customfield} should work for that

Comment: yes, you're right, `body` is apparently inside another tag - `issuelinks` Do you know how can I construct the last part of the query then? I tried `...?fields=issuelinks[body]` but it didn't work

Comment: I dont think that is possible through jira api. This is the most specifc json jira will return to you. I think you need to parse the returned json after.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this to retrieve only the description of the issue:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-123?fields=description
```

This returns

```
{
    "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
    "id": "10218",
    "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10218",
    "key": "KEY-123",
    "fields": {
        "description": "The issue description"
    }
}
```